# 401 Malformed HTTP basic Authorization header: Error on executing api through RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jenkins

I am trying to execute an api. This API is triggering a build on Jenkins. I am encoding my username and password and then setting it to headers. But it is giving me below error

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Malformed
>   HTTP basic Authorization header.

The api is executing fine with this curl:

```
curl -kX POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://XYZ' --user "username:password"
```

Jave programme:

```
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
String encodeBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("username" + "password").getBytes());
ManagementController.restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + encodeBytes);
headers.setContentType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(deployURL,HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
String message=response.getBody();
return modelAndView;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### Client side[[edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Basic_access_authentication&action=edit&section=5)]
>
> When the user agent wants to send authentication credentials to the server, it may use the *Authorization* field.
>
> The *Authorization* field is constructed as follows:[[6]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#cite_note-6)
>
> 1. **The username and password are combined with a single colon (:). This means that the username itself cannot contain a colon.**
> 2. The resulting string is encoded into an octet sequence. The character set to use for this encoding is by default unspecified, as long as it is compatible with US-ASCII, but the server may suggest use of UTF-8 by sending the *charset* parameter.[[7]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#cite_note-7)
> 3. The resulting string is encoded using a variant of [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).
> 4. The authorization method and a space (e.g. "Basic ") is then prepended to the encoded string.
>
> For example, if the browser uses Aladdin as the username and OpenSesame as the password, then the field's value is the base64-encoding of Aladdin:OpenSesame, or QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l. Then the Authorization header will appear as:
>
> `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l`
>
> -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side

I think you forgot to put a colon between the username and password here:

```
String encodeBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("username" + "password").getBytes());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method and pass username & password in headers

```
private HttpHeaders createHeaders(final String username, final String password) {
        return new HttpHeaders() {
            {
                if (!StringUtils.isBlank(username)) {
                    String auth = username + ":" + password;
                    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
                    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
                    set("Authorization", authHeader);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```